# Oozie Workflow with Archive Action

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, archive, oozie

I would like to make an oozie workflow where the final step of success would be to "Archive" the results.

The command in the shell to do it is

```
hadoop archive -archiveName=XXX.har -p /some/random/parent directorToArhive pathToArchiveDestination
```

I have tried the following

```
<workflow-app name="HARD_CODED_ARCHIVE_TEST" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">

    <start to="archive"/>
    <action name="archive">
        <archive archiveName="xxx.har" src="/root/src/dir" dest="/path/to/desired/archive/location"/>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

The Error I get is something like the following:

```
WARNING: Exception in Runloop of thread: main with message: E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'archive'. One of '{"uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":map-reduce, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":pig, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":sub-workflow, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":fs, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":java, WC[##other:"uri:oozie:workflow:0.4"]}' is expected.
```

So it is very clear that I can't do this.  because the oozie workflow schema does not support the "archive" action.

I really don't want to run this via a cron as I would like to archive immediately after a workflow completes successfully how do I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`<action name="archive">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <main-class>org.apache.hadoop.tools.HadoopArchives</main-class>
            <arg>-archiveName</arg>
            <arg>${YourArchiveName}.har</arg>
            <arg>-p</arg>
            <arg>${FilesParentDirectory}</arg>
            <arg>${SrcDirectory}</arg>
            <arg>${DestDirectory}</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="error"/>
    </action>`

All you need is the hadoop-archives.jar file in your workflow. Also don't forget to put the jar in your workflow directory and you should be good to go. Hope that helps!